# setSendTimeout before or after open

Tags: php, sockets

In php, when I want to set a timeout for a socket, should I call `setSendTimeout()` method before calling `open()` or after calling `open()`?

Answer (score 1):

You would set the timeout after opening the socket, and before sending.  If you set it after you would be blocking on the send anyway.

I assume you are using `socket_set_option` which takes the open socket as its first argument, so it would certainly need to be after.

What is `setSendTimeout`?  I have never seen that before.